# How to make the read operation occur only one time in the pSeudo driver here?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to write a kernel driver program. However, when I do the cat operation on cat /dev/pSeudoDrv. It just keeps printing the value. It never exits. I was assuming that the cat operation should exit after reading once. However, it is reading forever. What is the problem here?

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h> /** needed by all modules **/
#include <linux/kernel.h>  /** This is for KERN_ALERT **/
#include <linux/fs.h> /** for file operations **/
#include <linux/cdev.h>  /** character device **/
#include <linux/device.h>  /** for sys device registration in /dev/ and /sys/class **/
/** for copy_to_user **/
#include <asm/uaccess.h>


/** For class registration to work, you need GPL license **/
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");


static struct cdev basicCdev;
static struct class *basicDriverClass;

static int  basicMajorNumber = 0;

/** Prototype for read, this will be invoked when the read function is done on to the driver **/
/** The declaration type is file operations based function pointer - read **/
static ssize_t basicRead(struct file *filp, char *buffer, size_t length,loff_t *offset);

static int basicOspen(struct inode *inode, struct file *file);   

/** File Operations function pointer table **/
/** There are plenty of file operations  **/

static struct file_operations fops = {
  .read = basicRead,
  .write = NULL,
  .open = basicOspen,
  .release = NULL
};

static ssize_t basicRead(struct file *filp, char *buffer, size_t length, loff_t *offset)
{
     char msg[1024] = "Hello SJ_read\0";
     printk(KERN_ALERT "The Read operation called\r\n");
     copy_to_user( buffer, msg, sizeof(msg) );
     return sizeof(msg);
}

static int basicOspen(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{

   printk("Kernel.Basic Driver Opened now!!\r\n");

   return 0;
}

static void setup_cdev(struct cdev *dev, int minor, struct file_operations *fops)
{
         int err = -1;
         /** MKDEV call creates a device number i.e. combination of major and minor number **/
         int devno = MKDEV(basicMajorNumber, minor);
         /** Initiliaze character dev with fops **/
         cdev_init(dev, fops);
         /**owner and operations initialized **/
         dev->owner = THIS_MODULE;
         dev->ops = fops;
         /** add the character device to the system**/
         /** Here 1 means only 1 minor number, you can give 2 for 2 minor device, the last param is the count of minor number enrolled **/
         err = cdev_add (dev, devno, 1);

         if (err)
         {
                 printk (KERN_NOTICE "Couldn't add cdev");
         }
 }

static int chrDriverInit(void)
{

    int result;
    dev_t dev; 

    printk("Welcome!! Device Init now..");

    /** int alloc_chrdev_region(dev_t *dev, unsigned int firstminor,unsigned int count, char *name);  **/
    /** dev -> The dev_t variable type,which will get the major number that the kernel allocates.  **/
    /**The same name will appear in /proc/devices.  **/

    /** it is registering the character device **/   
    /** a major number will be dynamically allocated here **/
    result = alloc_chrdev_region(&dev, 0, 1, "pSeudoDrv");

    if( result < 0 )
    {
      printk("Error in allocating device");
      return -1;    
    }

    /** From these two if's we are avoiding the manual mknod command to create the /dev/<driver> **/
    /**  creating class, and then device created removes the dependency of calling mknod  **/
    /** A good method - the mknod way is depreciated **/
    /** mknod way is -  mknod /dev/<driver_name> c <majorNumber> <minorNumber>


    /** add the driver to /sys/class/chardrv **/
    if ((basicDriverClass = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "chardrv")) == NULL)    //$ls /sys/class
    {
        unregister_chrdev_region(dev, 1);
        return -1;
    }

     /** add the driver to /dev/pSeudoDrv -- here **/
    if (device_create(basicDriverClass, NULL, dev, NULL, "pSeudoDrv") == NULL) //$ls /dev/
    {
        class_destroy(basicDriverClass);
        unregister_chrdev_region(dev, 1);
        return -1;
    }

     /** let's see what major number was assigned by the Kernel **/
     basicMajorNumber = MAJOR(dev);
     printk("Kernel assigned major number is %d ..\r\n",basicMajorNumber );

    /** Now setup the cdev **/
    setup_cdev(&basicCdev, 0, &fops);

    return 0;   

}


static void chrDriverExit(void)
{
    /** A reverse - destroy mechansim -- the way it was created **/
    printk("Releasing Simple Devs -- %s\r\n",  __FUNCTION__);
    /** delete the character driver added **/
    cdev_del(&basicCdev);
    /** destroy the device created **/
    device_destroy(basicDriverClass, MKDEV(basicMajorNumber, 0));
    /** destroy the class created **/
    class_destroy(basicDriverClass);
    /** unregister the chr dev **/
    unregister_chrdev(basicMajorNumber, "pSeudoDrv");

}


module_init(chrDriverInit);
module_exit(chrDriverExit);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your return value in `basicRead`.

From LDD3:

> The return value for read is interpreted by the calling application
>   program:
>
> - If the value equals the count argument passed to the read system call, the requested number of bytes has been transferred. This is the
>     optimal case.
> - If the value is positive, but smaller than count, only part of the data has been transferred. This may happen for a number of reasons,
>     depending on the device. Most often, the application program retries
>     the read. For instance, if you read using the fread function, the
>     library function reissues the system call until completion of the
>     requested data transfer.
> - If the value is 0, end-of-file was reached (and no data was read).
> - A negative value means there was an error. The value specifies what the error was, according to . Typical values returned
>     on error include -EINTR (interrupted system call) or -EFAULT (bad
>     address).

In your case sizeof(msg) is smaller then length and it indicates userspace about partial read.
If you don't care about partial reads you can simply do `return length;` so userspace would know that read is done.

Otherwise, you should make sense of `filp` and `offset`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578949/in-my-read-function-myread-it-is-continuously-printing-the-read-data-when-i-do-c               This explains the exact thing. Returning  length would not stop the infinite read because cat command needs EOF or End of File to stop read further which is not given n your case.

Answer (score 3):

You MUST return 0 to let user-space process know that driver has copied all data and is at end of file.

If you return length, provided in the argument of read file operation, the calls will keep coming.

To avoid this you must increase "loff_t *offset" with the amount of bytes you copied in user-space "char *buffer" and return the exact number. This "*offset" will keep its value when the next read call will arrive.

Now you will get another call for read. You will have to compare your "*offset" with the "size of kernel data" you need to copy to user-space. If "*offset" is greater than or equal to "size of kernel data", you should return 0. This will let user-space program to know that there are no more data available in file (or device) and the process will stop reading.